# How to make Gnome-Shell run smooth in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: configuration, gnome-shell, responsiveness

My computer is an HP notebook with Intel i3 and Nvidia and SSD. Proprietary graphics drive are installed. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 as a new installation (instead of upgrading from 16.04).
I really miss the responsiveness of Ubuntu 16.04.

The overall cpu load is less than 10%. "top" shows Gnome-shell at 3.3%, and Chrome at 2%.

The CPU/GPU temperature is around 57 Celcius.

RAM usage with a lot of tabs opened in Chrome are still less than 2 of the 4 GB available.

Also I have tweaked "IO Schedulers" to deadline by doing

```
     echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
     echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/queue/iosched/fifo_batch
```

I also disabled "smooth scroll" on Libreoffice which gives me the best results in tweaking but the computer still feels sluggish.

Comment: If you do not find a solution, you would need to file a bug report with nvidia as it is a 3rd party closed source driver - https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/522835/linux/if-you-have-a-problem-please-read-this-first/

Comment: @panther thank you, but why do you think the problem is with the nvidia proprietary driver? For example the system freeze for a second when sending a file to print, and it is slow to open applications.